# How do I take out the caching and bandwidth optimizations sections out of the performance window for a user?

Tags: routes, hooks, users

How do I take out caching and bandwidth optimizations sections out of the performance window for a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`#access`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#access) property to do this.  You would just need to wrap things up in your own logic.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_system_performance_settings_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  if (user_cant_access_this_stuff()) {
    $form['caching']['#access'] = FALSE;
    $form['bandwidth_optimization']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

I am not 100% sure on those `$form` elements (this was taken from something similar I have on a site), so you may need to `dpm()` the `$form`.